# Namenode directory in surprising location

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have set the dfs.name.dir in the hdfs-site.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>>/mnt/data/nn</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>>/mnt/data/dfs</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

However the namenode is trying to access the following directory:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.2.1/libexec/>/mnt/data/nn
```

This happens to be the value of:

```
$HADOOP_HOME>[value of dfs.name.dir]
```

Following is the namenode log:

```
2013-11-01 13:38:59,806 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length = 0
2013-11-01 13:38:59,806 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2013-11-01 13:38:59,808 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.2.1/libexec/>/mnt/data/nn does not exist
2013-11-01 13:38:59,809 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.2.1/libexec/>/mnt/data/nn is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:304)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to note that maybe causing you this problem:

1. The NameNode reads it's configuration from a file named hdfs-site.xml (from $HADOOP_CONF dir), not hive-site.xml as you note in your question (i'm guessing that you've copied this from hdfs-site.xml into this file)
2. Check your config in hdfs-site.xml - if you have copied the config over, it looks like you have a leading > before your desired directory:

   - `<value>>/mnt/data/dfs</value>` *<< change from this value*
   - `<value>/mnt/data/dfs</value>` *<< amend to this value*

Comment: it is hdfs-site.xml not hive-site.xml  but your #2 is spot-on. good eyes!